# Android: org.json.JSON.typeMismatch

Tags: java, android, json

I've got a method below, which is parsing JSON. However I've run into an error (which you can see from the title), where it is saying "org.json.JSON.typeMismatch" .

Trying to log the names that are getting output however having no luck. I've little experience with cracking JSON (as you can probably tell from this), so wondering how to go about fixing this issue.

```
private Boolean parse()
{
    try
    {
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo;

        realms.clear();

        for (int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {

            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = jo.getString("name");
                Log.d("",name);


            //realms.add(name);


        }

        return true;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the JSON I am trying to parse into here is:

```
{
"realms": [{
    "type": "pvp",
    "population": "low",
    "queue": false,
    "status": true,
    "name": "Aegwynn",
    "slug": "aegwynn",
    "battlegroup": "Misery",
    "locale": "de_DE",
    "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
    "connected_realms": ["aegwynn"]
}, {
    "type": "pve",
    "population": "low",
    "queue": false,
    "status": true,
    "name": "Aerie Peak",
    "slug": "aerie-peak",
    "battlegroup": "Reckoning / Abrechnung",
    "locale": "en_GB",
    "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
    "connected_realms": ["bronzebeard", "aerie-peak"]
}]
```

(there is more to this but I'd rather not copy it all)

Not sure if perhaps I'm not addressing the "realms" array? Just would appreciate any help on this! As I can't see quite why I'm getting a mismatch?

Kind Regards

J G

Comment: it seems that you are trying to reach one level higher rather than the name. The way I am seeing it from what you have there, you need first to access realms and then iterate for the objects which objects contain the property "name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON string show up here it is a JSONObject not a JSONArray, so that you must init an JSONObject with this string, after that get a JSONArray with name `realms` from previous JSONObject. [Here is an example](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-json-parsing-tutorial) for your reference

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much for the quick response! That link you gave explained JSON in a good manner to me for android. Doing "  String name = jo.optString("name").toString();" was the key link for me, as well as the JSONArray with realms. 
Thank you once again, really appreciate it